# Does Main UI and AsyncTask runs on same thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I Found this while i was trying to show a loading message or you can say a progressbar on my activity.

I tried printing thread id using `Thread.currentThread.getId()` in both UI thread as well as AsyncTask. Both prints 1.

If both runs on the same thread then how can we change UI (suggested to do in `onPreExecute`) while running the complex task (suggested to do in `doInBackground`).

Kindly explain

Comment: Where in AsyncTask were you printing the thread id?

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground()` runs on a background thread, and then only if you use `AsyncTask` properly.

`doInBackground()` cannot directly change the UI, as it is running on a background thread. If you have changes you need to make while `doInBackground()` is running, call `publishProgress()`. This triggers a call to `onProgressUpdate()`, and that will be called on the main application thread.

For example, this retained fragment has an `AsyncTask` that will add words to a `ListView`, via its `ArrayAdapter`, as the words become available (using `Thread.sleep()` to simulate delays from network I/O):

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2014 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.async;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AsyncDemoFragment extends ListFragment {
  private static final String[] items= { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
      "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi",
      "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam",
      "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales",
      "pellentesque", "augue", "purus" };
  private ArrayList<String> model=new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=null;
  private AddStringTask task=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    task=new AddStringTask();
    task.execute();

    adapter=
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                 model);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (task != null) {
      task.cancel(false);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
      for (String item : items) {
        if (isCancelled())
          break;

        publishProgress(item);
        SystemClock.sleep(400);
      }

      return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
      if (!isCancelled()) {
        adapter.add(item[0]);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();

      task=null;
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask) described in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android))

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` execute command is run on `Main UiThread` but `doInBackground` runs on `worker thread` which implies that `Thread.currentThread.getId()` in `doInBackground()` will return the different number.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the Async Task actually creates a new Thread in `doInBackground()` using the HaMeR framework. So it really depends on where you are printing the thread id.